# PHP code to traverse through a HTML file to find all the images in there?

Tags: php

I wanted a php script to fetch all the images in HTML code and list it.
Can anyone help me do this, or some Idea as to how I should proceed ?
I am new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Given the answers and the fact one has even been given 3 up votes, it would be good to accept the answer you like most so people get the appropriate recognition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), or [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). here is a DOMDocument example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($yourHtmlAsAString);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    echo $img->getAttribute('src').'<br>'; // or whatever you need
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Run the HTML code through one of the [many HTML parser libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) and then query for the src attribute value on all the img elements.

Answer (score 3):

Tried looking at DOMDocument in PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Good example from that page:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->prevservWhiteSpace = false;

$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);

$imageList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$imageCnt  = $imageList->length;

for ($idx = 0; $idx < $imageCnt; $idx++) {
    print $imageList->item($idx)->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Should give you the basics you need.

*Disclaimer, example is slightly modified from the comment I yanked it from but this is pretty straight forward stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load it from an actual php/html file...

```
$dom = new DomDocument();

if (!@$dom->load('img.php')) {
    echo 'url does not exist';
    return;
}

$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

for ($buffer = ''; $i = 0, $len = $imgs->length; $i < $len; $i++)
{
  $buffer .= 'image ' . $i . ' is: ' . $imgs->item($i)->getAttribute('src') . '<br/>';
}

echo $buffer;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot eveyone for the code, it works just fine. Nw I knw DomDocument can do magic :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the [DOM](http://www.php.net/dom). It should provide the functionality you are looking for.